# Selecting unique entries from a column

Tags: mysql

I have this table
              ID  |     Category     |    Subcategory   |

```
           1  |      Books       |    Comic         |
           2  |      Books       |   Fiction        |
           3  |      Cars        |     New          |
           4  |      Books       |   Non- fiction   |
           4  |      Cars        |    Second hand   |
```

and  I want to select only unique entries from the column 'Category'.
That is, I want 'Books' and 'Cars' to be selected only once. 
How can  I write a query ?? 
Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean distinct ?

```
SELECT Distinct Category
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Or group by

```
SELECT Category
FROM Table
GROUP BY Category
```

Group by enables you to retrieve various aggregates based on your query (such as number of items in category etc...)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
This was my first visit to the site and  I got answer really fast.
Thanks once again.